# Waiting for unzip to finish before carrying on C++ code on a RedHat machine

Tags: c++, zip, redhat, unzip

I want to unzip a zipped folder on my Redhat machine.

To do this I send a bash script the string;

```
"unzip /usr/bin/Folder.gz"
```

This unzips the folder no problem, as in I get the general

```
inflating folderA/folderB/fileX
```

etc.

---

However, I want to hold the code at the unzip command, waiting until the unzipping is complete.

I have tried using

```
sleep(5)
```

but I don’t want to use this and just hope that it will always take less than five seconds especially this is would be inefficient for very small zipped files.

I have searched online but to no avail...

So my question is; what is a reliable way to stall a program until the unzipping is complete?

---

O/S: Redhat

Programming Language: C++

IDE: Eclipse

Comment: How do you send the string - ie the C++ code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you run the bash script?

If you use the `system()` API it will start the program and then wait until the spawned process ends.

`system()` system is a call that is made up of 3 other system calls: execl(), wait() and fork(). [Source](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node22.html).

Comment: I have used the system command as you have suggested. However there are many people out there who say that using a the system command is taboo. Why is this and what should be done instead?

Comment: @Andy: That's a relevant question, but another question and this one. Please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
unzip /usr/bin/Folder.gz &
wait $!
```

That will cause the shell to wait on the completion of the last process. The pid of the last executed command is stored in `$!`.

Not sure how this relates to C++, but if you want to do the same from code you can use the `waitpid` function.

Of course, if you want your program to block while `unzip` executes I'm a little confused as to what the exact problem is. Assuming you're using `system` or some equivalent to run unzip, it should block until the command completes.

Comment: Why not use simply `unzip /usr/bin/Folder.gz` without the `&` ? In C++, you'd simply do `system("unzip /usr/bin/Folder.gz")` (instead of fork/execve/while waitpid)

Comment: That's correct, and I edited my answer shortly after. I was under the impression the OP wanted to do work while waiting for `unzip` to finish, and then to join on the completion of the process.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure this is the best way, but it is reliable.
Now instead just sending the command to the bash why not send the output to some file.

```
unzip /usr/bin/Folder.gz > output.txt
```

Read the file in regular intervals from your C++ code (lets say 1 sec) once you find 100% or whatever the last line of the output should contain and then carry on with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would be overkill or inefficent, but you could move the process of unzipping in to another thread, and halt your main thread until that thread is finished processing