# Detecting overwrites when using unzip from command line in Redhat

Tags: c++, redhat, unzip

Possibly this should be on Superuser, but I'm using it in code so thought I'd start here.

My C++ program unzips a .gz file using the "system()" call. (Yes I know it's taboo, but it was the best of a bad lot when I started this project a while back, and I asked [Unzipping a file from C++ on Redhat: alternatives to system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022990/unzipping-a-file-from-c-on-redhat-alternatives-to-system) when I thought I'd have the chance to improve it, but I haven't managed to implement anything yet)

As there is a chance that a file with the same name already exists, the unzip call uses the "-o" modifier to for an over-write.

Is there a way to detect that there has been an overwrite? I am open to alternatives to system() and unzip.

---

OS: Redhat

Language: C++

IDE: Eclipse

Comment: If you are using `system` rather than a library, the behavior will be that of the application that you are calling, and the problem is no longer programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the obvious answer would be to try to detect whether there is a file with the appropriate name on disk before you even run the `system` command; if a file exists prior to unzipping, then an overwrite will occur. You can easily check whether a file exists by `fopen`ing it with a mode of `"r"` and checking the return value for a valid file handle. (Don't forget to `fclose` the file if it does already exist.)

Comment: Of course! Sorry, hadn't thought about doing it that way at all! Thanks!