# What could cause unzip command returning -1 in my scenario?

Tags: c++, linux, unzip

I run unzip via a `system()` call in my C++ code in below format:

```
/usr/bin/unzip -o -q /<my_path_to_zip_file>/cfg_T-KTMAKUCB.zip -d /<my_path_to_dest>/../
```

This will almost 90% of times succeed. I cannot understand what could make it fail time to time with -1 return code. Any ideas?

Comment: Please share your version of `unzip`.

Comment: Why not pipe the error stream to a log file? You could create a unit test which runs the command ~100 times and then check the log file to see what the error was?

Comment: Does the user calling the program have all necessary permissions to access directories? Is there enough space on the device to unzip the file? If you run the program with `sudo` does it help? Also, the `-1` returned from `system()` does not mean it is the return value of `unzip` (see `man 3 sleep` for details). Give some more information

Comment: @Rogus As he stated it works most of the time, permissions and sudo are clearly not solutions. Disk size could be, though I think it's unlikely. Good point about the return code. Indeed, unzip will never return < 0

Comment: @arminb unzip version: Compiled with gcc 4.9.2 for Unix (Linux ELF) on Feb  3 2017.

Comment: @Michael unfortunatley the process of reproducing it is not as easy since running on embedded system and the chance of it not appearing is high. Perhaps what 'Useless' recommends in the answer is an option.

Comment: What, checking `errno` after an error is returned? You should definitely be doing that anyway.

Comment: As mentioned we are checking for `errno` and it is `-1`.

Comment: In your question you said "-1 return code", not errno.  What errno are you checking? I believe errno's are process unique, thus you don't have access to the unzip errno.  Perhaps you should investigate "explain_system()".  "The explain_system function is used to obtain an explanation of an error returned by the system(3) system call. The least the message will contain is the value of strerror(errno), but usually it will do much better, and indicate the underlying cause in more detail. "

Comment: Did you consider invoking unzip directly from your C++ (without 'system()')  I have used zlib in an embedded system successfully.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7022990/2785528

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN `explain_system()` is a good point. `zlib` does not help me with `ZIP` extraction. Need to use something from `UNZIP` and call `UzpUnzipToMemory` for example. Currently trying to find an example usage for `UzpUnzipToMemory`.

Comment: Can you add a sample code how do you call the command above, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According my local `man system`,

> The value returned is -1 on error (e.g.  fork(2) failed), and the return status of the command otherwise.

and the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) says,

> If a child process cannot be created, or if the termination status for the command language interpreter cannot be obtained, system() shall return -1 and set errno to indicate the error

Finally, the manpage for `unzip` lists various return codes, but -1 isn't among them.

If the command itself can't return -1, the problem is probably with the initial `fork`/`exec`, due to something like a system-wide or per-user limit (memory exhausted; process table full; maximum processes, open files or VM size limit for the user etc. etc).

You should be checking `errno` when `system` fails anyway. Running the whole thing under `strace -f` will also show what happens.

Comment: Good point on return code -1 being caused on initial `fork`/`exec`. One thing I can be sure is that I am sure none of the: "memory exhausted; process table full; maximum processes, open files or VM size limit" are the cause. So wonder what `strace -f` may give.